# Fixing my macro to copy a range to the next blank column?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a cell range into the next blank column in a separate sheet, every time the forms buttons for the macro is clicked.

Here's the code. The problem is it copies to the next blank *row*, and I need the next blank column. I have tried editing the line* in various ways and end up with errors, or no effect (e.g. replacing "Rows" with "Columns").

- Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

If found the base for the 'copy to next blank row VBA' here at SO, at the following link:
[Copy and Paste a set range in the next empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976329/copy-and-paste-a-set-range-in-the-next-empty-row)

Thanks for any help, I'm stuck currently.

```
Sub TestCopyToDB()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

    copySheet.Range("M1:M15").Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Although @DavidZemens got it covered, you can [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485791/excel-vba-paste-problems/20487279#20487279) for additional info on *Cells Property*.

Comment: @L42, thank you very much, that really was enlightening, as was DavidZemens's answer. I asked one question and learned much more than one answer thanks to both of you; SE rocks! (I tried up voting your answer but I can't, so I wanted to thank you here.)

Comment: Np :) You can try again once you gained enough rep. Also, another way of thanking is to help the community if you can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Cells` method has two arguments, *row* and *column*, i.e.,

```
Cells(1,1)   '<~~ equivalent to cell "A1"
Cells(1,3)   '<~~ equivalent to cell "C1"
Cells(10,13) '<~~ equivalent to cell "M10"
```

The `Offset` method works similarly, with two arguments, *row_offset*, and *column_offset*, so:

```
.Offset(1,1)   '<~~ returns the cell one row below, and one column to the right
.Offset(-1, 3) '<~~ returns the cell one row above, and 3 columns to the right
```

Making some adjustments, and change the `.End(xlUp)` (for rows) to `.End(xlToLeft)`, gives this:

```
With pasteSheet
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```